# Family of parts

Tags: modifiers, objects

In some CAD softwares I founded a function called "family of parts" that with base of a created object, I can do anothers with the same base but changing some aspects like the radio or some array attached to it. Is some way in blender that I can do the same?

The example is with the gears of one bike, creating the largest gear and with the family of parts function, I can do the another gears in a array with a proportional reduction of the radio and how much teeth can have each one in the array.

Comment: Hi David. Nothing similar in Blender, Just copy object/group press "Shift+D" and change the duplicate.

Comment: There is no "family of parts" in blender, but you can create links. Their usefulness depend on which aspects of the original part you want to change and have the changes applied to the copies.